# Interfaces o tipo con parametros dependientes

Tags: typescript

tengo esta interfaz, como puedo hacer que los parámetros opcionales dependan de algún campo, "text" siempre debe de estar.
Si esta el campo "to" entonces "permission" es requerido y "subItems" no debe esta estar y si no esta el campo  "to" entonces "subItems" es requerido y "permission" no debe de estar

```
interface item  {
  text: string,
  to?: string,
  subItems?:subItems[]
  permission?: string
}
```

item1 y item2 están bien, item3 debería marcar error

```
const item1:item  = {
   text:"item 1",
   to :"/",
   permision: "1"
}
   const item2:item  = {
   text:"item 1",
   subItems:[]
}
   const item3:item  = {
   text:"item 3",
   to:"/"
   subItems:[],
   permision:"1"
}
```

Probé usando tipos de esta forma pero anqué este "to" permite "subMenu"

```
type item_<to = string|undefined> = to extends string
  ? {
      text: string,
      to: string,
      permission: string
    }
  : {
      text: string,
      subMenu: subSubItem[]
    };
   
const item3:item_ = { text:"item3",to:"/", subMenu:[]}
```

Comment: Yo entiendo como campo "NO requerido" a que es opcional, es decir puede o no estar. Entonces en el caso donde está el campo `to`,  que el campo `subMenu` esté presente es válido.  O tu con "NO requerido" te refieres a otra cosa?

Comment: @Yussef Me refería a que no pueda estar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a simplificar el ejemplo, digamos que tenemos 2 interfaces y un `type` que puede ser lo uno u lo otro

```
interface Iitem  {
  text: string;
  to: string;
  permission: string;
}

interface Iitem2  {
  text: string;
  subItems:string;
}

type Item = Iitem | Iitem2;
```

El ejemplo anterior tiene el mismo problema que tu señalas, y se soluciona explicitando que `to` será `undefined`

```
interface Iitem  {
  text: string;
  to: string;
  permission: string;
}

interface Iitem2  {
  text: string;
  to?: undefined; //<-- ESTO ES LO NECESARIO
  subItems:string;
}

type item_ = Iitem | Iitem2;
const item1:item_ = {  text:"item3", subItems:""} //bien
const item2:item_ = {  to:"", text:"item3", permission:""} //bien
const item3:item_ = {  to:"", text:"item3", subItems:""} //error
const item4:item_ = {  text:"item3", permission:""} //error
```